# How to open, edit, then save Dropbox file

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I have a web app that can edit files. It runs entirely client side, with only a static content server.

I want a user to go to my site, selects the file from Dropbox, edits it using my app, then saves it back.

This is possible with Drive (e.g. https://github.com/googledrive/web-quickeditor, hosted at https://github.com/googledrive/web-quickeditor), with only a static content sever (HTML, JS, CSS)...*no database or any other server setup needed.*

Is this possible with Dropbox? Their [file picker](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) doesn't allow me to write back to Dropbox. There's [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js), but that doesn't have a file picker.

What is the expected way that I open, edit, and save from JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dropbox Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver) would allow the user to save files back to their account, but the app needs to be able to supply a URL for the new file.

Alternatively, you could use [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) as you mentioned. There's no reason you can't use both the [Dropbox Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) and [dropbox-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js).

Comment: Indeed, I found the combination of Dropbox Chooser and dropbox-js to be what another app was doing. The Chooser gives you a URL which you can use string-fu on to obtain the the path needed for dropbox-js. (This isn't guaranteed that I can, but I see no other way.)

Comment: Links from the Chooser don't exactly offer a way to get the full/original path, but you can use the "direct" link type and download from them directly. (Or modify the "preview" link type if necessary: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 )